# Filtering data using 'AND' condition of inputs given

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, array-filter

I am facing an issue where I should filter the data based on '&&' condition of inputs given.

The data to be filtered

```
let ssData={
         "0": {
             "OnPower": "no",
              "hazard": "no",
               "issues": "no",
               "OnGenerator": "no",
              "PermanentFuel": "no",
              "onDamage": "no"
      },
      "1": {
            "OnPower": "yes",
            "hazard": "yes",
            "issues": "no",
            "OnGenerator": "yes",
            "PermanentFuel": "no",
            "onDamage": "yes"
      },
      "2": {
            "OnPower": "no",
            "hazard": "no",
            "issues": "no",
            "OnGenerator": "yes",
            "PermanentFuel": "yes",
            "onDamage": "no"
      },
      "3": {
            "OnPower": "yes",
            "hazard": "yes",
            "issues": "yes",
            "OnGenerator": "yes",
            "PermanentFuel": "yes",
            "onDamage": "yes"
      },
      "4": {
            "OnPower": "no",
            "hazard": "yes",
            "issues": "no",
            "OnGenerator": "no",
            "PermanentFuel": "no",
            "onDamage": "yes"
      },
      "5": {
            "OnPower": "yes",
            "hazard": "no",
            "issues": "no",
            "OnGenerator": "yes",
            "PermanentFuel": "no",
            "onDamage": "no"
      },
      "6": {
            "OnPower": "yes",
            "hazard": "no",
            "issues": "yes",
            "OnGenerator": "no",
            "PermanentFuel": "no",
            "onDamage": "yes"
      }
}
```

input to filtering is :

```
 let filterData= ["OnPower","hazard","OnGenerator"]
```

**The filtering should be done by comparing with "yes" value  and using "AND" condition from input**

```
export function filterWithMultipleIssueData(ssData, filterData){
   let filteredSSData=[]
    ssData.map((row,index)=>{
        filterData.map((field)=>{
            if(row[field] == 'yes'){
                 filteredSSData.push(row.toJS())
            }
        })
    })
    return filteredSSData
}
```

In the above function , Im getting filteredSSData using 'OR' condition.(OnPower 'OR' hazard 'OR' OnGenerator)

The Comparision should be with OnPower 'AND' hazard 'AND' OnGenerator

```
The expected Output is:  

{
       "1": {
            "OnPower": "yes",
            "hazard": "yes",
            "issues": "no",
            "OnGenerator": "yes",
            "PermanentFuel": "no",
            "onDamage": "yes"
      },
      "3": {
            "OnPower": "yes",
            "hazard": "yes",
            "issues": "yes",
            "OnGenerator": "yes",
            "PermanentFuel": "yes",
            "onDamage": "yes"
      },
}
```

Comment: Format your question properly please.

Comment: Formatting code properly on this site is *extremely* easy.

Comment: ...and we dont need all of your data. 1 ~ 3 examples of valid input/output are enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `map` on filtered you might wana use `every` instead:

```
 function filterYes(data, keys){
   return data.filter(data => keys.every(key => data[key] === "yes"));
 }
```

I guess your data is an array (cause you call `map` on it) otherwise its a bit more complicated:

```
 function filterYes(data, key){
  return Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(data).filter(([key, value]) =>
     keys.every(key => value[key] === "yes")
 ).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with `higher-order` functions:

- map
- filter
- reduce

```js
let ssData={
         "0": {
             "OnPower": "no",
              "hazard": "no",
               "issues": "no",
               "OnGenerator": "no",
              "PermanentFuel": "no",
              "onDamage": "no"
      },
      "1": {
            "OnPower": "yes",
            "hazard": "yes",
            "issues": "no",
            "OnGenerator": "yes",
            "PermanentFuel": "no",
            "onDamage": "yes"
      },
      "2": {
            "OnPower": "no",
            "hazard": "no",
            "issues": "no",
            "OnGenerator": "yes",
            "PermanentFuel": "yes",
            "onDamage": "no"
      },
      "3": {
            "OnPower": "yes",
            "hazard": "yes",
            "issues": "yes",
            "OnGenerator": "yes",
            "PermanentFuel": "yes",
            "onDamage": "yes"
      },
      "4": {
            "OnPower": "no",
            "hazard": "yes",
            "issues": "no",
            "OnGenerator": "no",
            "PermanentFuel": "no",
            "onDamage": "yes"
      },
      "5": {
            "OnPower": "yes",
            "hazard": "no",
            "issues": "no",
            "OnGenerator": "yes",
            "PermanentFuel": "no",
            "onDamage": "no"
      },
      "6": {
            "OnPower": "yes",
            "hazard": "no",
            "issues": "yes",
            "OnGenerator": "no",
            "PermanentFuel": "no",
            "onDamage": "yes"
      }
};

let filterData= ["OnPower","hazard","OnGenerator"];

function filterDataFunction(dataToFilter, filterOptions) {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(dataToFilter)
    .map(elem => ssData[elem]) // convert object to array
    .filter(data => 
       filterOptions
          .map(filter => data[filter] === 'yes') // filter data where specified answers equal yes
          .reduce((first, second) => first && second)); // perform && on all elements of the array
}

console.log(filterDataFunction(ssData, filterData));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an Array, but you can do this with `Object.entries().filter().reduce()`.

```
let result = Object.entries(ssData)
  .filter(([_, o]) => filterData.every(k => o[k] === "yes"))
  .reduce((res, [k, o]) => Object.assign(res, {[k]: o}), {});
```

---

*Click for demo:*

```js
let ssData = {
      "0": {
        "OnPower": "no",
        "hazard": "no",
        "issues": "no",
        "OnGenerator": "no",
        "PermanentFuel": "no",
        "onDamage": "no"
      },
      "1": {
        "OnPower": "yes",
        "hazard": "yes",
        "issues": "no",
        "OnGenerator": "yes",
        "PermanentFuel": "no",
        "onDamage": "yes"
      },
      "2": {
        "OnPower": "no",
        "hazard": "no",
        "issues": "no",
        "OnGenerator": "yes",
        "PermanentFuel": "yes",
        "onDamage": "no"
      },
      "3": {
        "OnPower": "yes",
        "hazard": "yes",
        "issues": "yes",
        "OnGenerator": "yes",
        "PermanentFuel": "yes",
        "onDamage": "yes"
      },
      "4": {
        "OnPower": "no",
        "hazard": "yes",
        "issues": "no",
        "OnGenerator": "no",
        "PermanentFuel": "no",
        "onDamage": "yes"
      },
      "5": {
        "OnPower": "yes",
        "hazard": "no",
        "issues": "no",
        "OnGenerator": "yes",
        "PermanentFuel": "no",
        "onDamage": "no"
      },
      "6": {
        "OnPower": "yes",
        "hazard": "no",
        "issues": "yes",
        "OnGenerator": "no",
        "PermanentFuel": "no",
        "onDamage": "yes"
      }
    };

    let filterData= ["OnPower","hazard","OnGenerator"];

    let result = Object.entries(ssData)
      .filter(([_, o]) => filterData.every(k => o[k] === "yes"))
      .reduce((res, [k, o]) => Object.assign(res, {[k]: o}), {});
      
      
    console.log(result);
```